# Redirection 301 with a url like http://www.mywebsite.com/?RT

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters

Google has indexed pages duplicating my homepage. 
I end up with URLs like mywebsite.com /? RT I want redirected to mywebsite.com / history to show that Google is not to duplicate. 
From what I understand, you need to use RewriteCond to do this but I can not redirect this seems not to be a URL to the server, but just my homepage ... without variable without way ...

A huge thank you for any contribution answer!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+s\?RT[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /history? [R=301,L]
```